# How to disable JavaScript setting in Microsoft Egde using Selenium/Java?

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

I've tried to use this one to solve this problem, but it doesn't disable javascript setting in the **Microsoft Edge** browser.
Could someone help with this?
Thanks!

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();

options.setCapability("javascript.enabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might be of some help:

```
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript", 2);
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
driver.get("site url");
```

Comment: Thank you! Such approach will work for Selenium version 4.
Unfortunately, my work project uses Selenium 3.
So, the problem is on the Selenium side.

Comment: @Anny You're welcome! In Selenium 3, I think you can use addPreference instead of setCapability. For example: options.addPreference("javascript.enabled", false);

Comment: I've found another way to use setExperimentalOption() in Selenium 3, which is to install [Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools).